# How to add background process in iphone?

Tags: iphone, background, multitasking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to run my application in background in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547477/how-to-run-my-application-in-background-in-iphone)

Hi friends. Am new for iphone applicaions. Now am struggle with add Background process in my application. That means i need to run my application after ckick "iphone HOME button". How can i do this.. Can anyone help me???

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What specifically do you want running in the background? A task? location? voice-over-ip? music?

Comment: I want to running task in background. And how i can check whether device supporting multitasking and background feature??? Thanks for reading my english.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since iOS 4.0 iPhone supports "multitasking" this means if you click the home button your app sleeps, this needs almost no battery or memory and if the iPhone run out of memory it will terminate sleeping applications.

Every app supports this kind of multitasking exepted you don't allow it for your app.

But there are also three real multitasking functions:

- VoIP
- GPS
- Music

Those three functions you can really use for multitasking apps. But nothing more...

Answer (score 0):

Your application will move to background,if your iPhone device support multitasking feature,
you can select and bring that in foreground, **And** multitasking is supported in iOS 4.0 and onward.

So for the **iOS 3.0 and below**, when you click on the **Home** button then your application is automatically terminated my iOS itself.

Comment: Thank you my friend. But i have one more doubt that is how to check whether the device is supporting multitask and background feature.. what code i need to implement. sorry for my poor english... Thank you my friend..

Comment: @Yuvaraj. M : Use UIDevice class to get the systemName and systemVersion valuse   see the apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html

Comment: @Yuvaraj. M :Accept if my answer help you.