# Running an app function from background- iPhone

Tags: ios, background, accelerometer

I need to create an app which can handle movement events while running on the background.
i.e each time an accelerometer event is happening it should be tracked in the application memory-when the application is running in the background.

My questions are :
1. Is it possible on IOS?
2. How can it be done?

(I came up with some relevant questions but i'm not sure that the answers are up to date due to IOS changes.)

Thanks,
Asaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547477/how-to-run-my-application-in-background-in-iphone) (and the links inside) and the [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).

To summarize no third party apps can run in the background (even though some of apple apps do this) excepting for:

- Tracking the User’s Location
- Playing Background Audio
- Implementing a VoIP App
- Downloading Newsstand Content in the Background
- Communicating With an External Accessory

Comment: I'm familiar with the apple documentation.can it be applied to the location tracking,since the accelerometer tracks motion? and if not is the answer to my question is a straight no?

Comment: Sorry but no, it's only to track the user's location. The better would be to have your application running on foreground and so track the accelerometer as usually...