# iPhone collecting CoreMotion data in the background. (longer than 10 mins)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, core-motion

I am trying to collect coreMotion acceleration data in the background for longer than 10 minutes. This must be possible since apps like Sleep Cycle do this.

I just want to make sure this is allowed though, since it does not seem to be one of these:

```
Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
Apps that record audio content while in the background.
Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories
Apps that implement these services must declare the services they support and use system frameworks to implement the relevant aspects of those services. Declaring the services lets the system know which services you use, but in some cases it is the system frameworks that actually prevent your application from being suspended.
```

However, I have tried following these steps to get a background task, but I am thinking there is a better way for CoreMotion:

Header:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
```

Code:

```
// if the iOS device allows background execution,
// this Handler will be called
- (void)backgroundHandler {

NSLog(@"### -->VOIP backgrounding callback");

UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

// Start the long-running task 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

while (1) {
    NSLog(@"BGTime left: %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
       [self doSomething];
    sleep(1);
}   
});     

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

BOOL backgroundAccepted = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{ [self backgroundHandler]; }];
if (backgroundAccepted)
{
    NSLog(@"VOIP backgrounding accepted");
}

UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];


// Start the long-running task
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    while (1) {
        NSLog(@"BGTime left: %f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
       [self doSomething];
       sleep(1);
    }    
}); 
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use this one:

```
Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
```

In other words, you make a location manager and tell it to start doing updates. You don't have to do anything with those updates! But as long as this is happening - that is, as long as your app is continuing to do location updates in the background - your app is also allowed to use Core Motion in the background. This is not just a trick; it is official Apple policy as explained in one of the WWDC videos from a couple of years ago.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, i'll give this a try. Would I still be able to process incoming accelerometer data at a rate I chose? (say every second or so?)

Comment: More so, if I want to get the accelerometer data say every second does that mean I have to be calling startUpdatingLocation every second in the background? Seems like it would be killing the battery extra fast this way hah.

Comment: You only call `startUpdatingLocation` once. That is what "start" means.

Comment: Is it also possible with that solution to get information about user walking/running/automotive in background mode and start location updates with that information e.g.gps?

Comment: @verklixt That makes no sense. If your app is in the background and wasn't already getting location updates when it went into the background, it is suspended. It therefore obviously can't "start" doing anything. (Also, you don't need to get core motion activity updates in the background; the device is always getting them for you.)

Comment: @matt thx for the answer.
I know that the core processor is receiving updates permanently.
What I mean, getting that information in my application permanently...
This should not take much battery charge, and only in certain conditions activate the gps...
This whole process when the application is pushed in background mode

Comment: @verklixt It isn't a question of battery charge or certain conditions. It has to do with the meaning of backgrounded. Did you watch the WWDC video on what's new in core location? They make it very clear what you can do and what you can't.

Comment: @matt you mentioned a WWDC video. Could you please clarify which exactly?

Comment: It's not good for the battery life, I wish there was another solution.

Comment: You sound very definitive about this - but - 1) can you please spare the link to the relevant WWDC talk? I'll need it - because it stopped working for me, and I want to complain to Apple. 2) I see inconsistent behaviour on iOS 12.1.x (I set up CoreMotion with some update interval (say 10 times a sec, for collecting Gyroscope info) and it just stops calling me after some time (arbitrary)

Comment: @verklixt can you please explain yourself? To get CoreMotion updates, you either register with a desired update interval (and provide a code block) or set up your own timer and call CoreMotion for updates. the M7 may receive updates in the background - but your app won't. I'm struggling now to get them - and experience arbitrary random behaviour on any iOS 12.1.x

Comment: @MottiShneor Might be WWDC 2012 Session 524, but at this distance in time it is hard to reconstruct. What "stopped working"? You are remembering that running core location in the background itself now has more requirements than before, yes?

Comment: @matt Ah... a lot happened since WWDC 2012. I'm not aware of "more requirements" - Can you direct me to related docs? I'm experiencing this: I need to collect and process "raw" sensor data (gyro, magnetometer, accelerometer) at constant (10Hz) rate - both in foreground and background. Actually - If the OS could record data for me - I would love to process it in foreground. I must have continuous sensor data. I provide CoreMotion with a queue, 0.1sec interval and a code-block. Sometimes it works in BG, but sometimes times interval increases when in BG - and CoreMotion updates stop completely.

Comment: @MottiShneor did you get that solved? I would like to get sensors data with up to 60Hz in background, but it just gives me 10 Hz data.

Comment: I found this WWDC session archive: https://pvieito.com/2022/05/wwdc-sessions-archive#wwdc-2012 but I didn't find any session mentioning to use location updates in combination with core motion.