# NSTImer in the background work only for some minutes

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

I have got NSTimer in my app checking in the background if it's needed to post a local notification, and it works pretty fine, but only for some minutes after entering the background mode. 
How can i make that NSTimer work all the time app is in the background?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible if you register for Long-running background tasks and needs to have a specific reason to get approval. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24)

Comment: I know that! I ask how to register for Long-running background tasks

Comment: I can describe my situation more sophisticated: I'm making a boxing timer which plays a gong sound at the end and start of each round (can look for some boxing timer in the appstore). I need my app to work in te background. How can that be emplemented?

Comment: Did you put as mentioned in your Info.plist the key `UIBackgroundModes` with value audio?

Comment: Yes i have, but timer still killed after some minutes

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789070/1505074) - he has done exactly what you want and to keep the app alive after the music is finished he used an NSTimer

Comment: Not working solution ;( It works but only for some minutes. maybe i'm writing something not right... Should i invalidate the background task before starting it again?