# Playing alarm tone in background after scheduling

Tags: ios, objective-c, alarm

i have a request to make a app , which is a alarm app ,

this app should has the capability to run the alarm song, if the app is in backgorund

But i have gone through with apple documents ,its pretty clear that . each and every app will stop execution after 3 mintes, Unless the app is in a special category

But i have a quesiton  ,  i download this app ,   https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/step-out-bed!-smart-alarm/id673120263?mt=8

this app has the capability  to run its alarm tone  when the app is in background ,  even if the app is in silent mode , how come this has the cpability to do that

have they enabled music play in background ,   or  have they configured inifinite background expiration handler , but can this causes reject app from

i have seen dozen of solutions for this implementations , but could nt  match working process for this matter , also i have contacted apple for this cause , and distribution , will update this once i get an update

Comment: Did you get any workaround for this  ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **UILocalNotification**. App will schedule the event and it will be dispatched by the system even if app is not running.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/

Comment: which is true , but in my question , app will be in background and  will be in silent mode , with default settings on UILocalNotification u cant play alarm song in silent mode