# Background location updates forever ios 8/9

Tags: ios

I'm developing a tracking application for ios 8/9. My application runs in background for about 15 min and then stops. I want to make it run for ever. Please suggest me some code sample or demo in swift language.

Thanks

Comment: Do you call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738488/run-app-for-more-than-10-minutes-in-background

Comment: Yes njuri , I call requestWhenInUseAuthorization in code

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CLLocationManager` property `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Njuri, You saved my day. Its working finally with  this code pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically to false.