# AS3 iPhone app that runs in the background

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, background

I'm developing an iPhone app using Actionscript 3.0. It uses GPS to send an email once you're within certain co-ordinates. At the moment the app automatically pauses itself when it's exited, and so isn't listening out for any geolocation changes and won't do it's job unless open.

Is there any way I can run the app in the background, or without actually being open?

Hope someone can help,
Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547477/how-to-run-my-application-in-background-in-iphone

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/05/04/air-ios-background-behavior/

So long as you set up your application descriptor properly, you can listen for location updates in the background.

You will also have to enable background task completion in the application descriptor if you want to send an email.